# Convert_This_statement into vb6

Tags: vb6

I have Faced A problem to covert a statement which is written in vb2010. i want to convert this statement into vb6, please help me anyone.
the code is

```
str=Textbox1.Text.Chars(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Can you tell what output it gives when you execute this code in vs2010?

Answer (score 4):

Word to word translation will be

```
myStr = Mid(Textbox1.Text, Len(Textbox1.Text), 1)
```

But you can use

```
myStr = Right(Textbox1.Text, 1)
```

EDIT

yes Mid & Right are variant type
And Mid$ and Right$ are string

```
myStr = Mid$(Textbox1.Text, Len(Textbox1.Text), 1)

'OR

myStr = Right$(Textbox1.Text, 1)
```